# TypeError Composer\Util\Filesystem::isAbsolutePath(): Argument #1 ($path) must be of type string, null given

Tags: composer-php, typeerror, upgrade, drupal-10

I'm trying to update my project's dependencies, the update is running, but crashing due to

> [TypeError]
> Composer\Util\Filesystem::isAbsolutePath(): Argument #1 ($path) must be of type string, null given, called in /path/to/project/folder/vendor/drupal-composer/preserve-paths/src/PluginWrapper.php on line 190.

My composer.json file contents:

```json
{
  "name": "zebralab/drupal-8",
  "description": "ZebraLab (Drupal 8) site.",
  "type": "project",
  "license": "GPL-2.0+",
  "repositories": {
    "lenient": {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/lenient"
    },
    "drupal-8": {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https://packages.drupal.org/8"
    },
    "drupal-typed_data_explorer": {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "type": "drupal-module",
        "name": "drupal/typed_data_explorer",
        "description": "Discover Typed Data API for Drupal. For more details, see http://lussoluca.github.io/DDD-2016/#/ .",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "dist": {
          "url": "https://github.com/wellnet/typed_data_explorer/archive/master.zip",
          "type": "zip"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "php": ">=8.1",
    "composer-plugin-api": "^2.0",
    "composer/installers": "^2",
    "cweagans/composer-patches": "^1.6",
    "davidbarratt/custom-installer": "^1.1",
    "drupal-composer/preserve-paths": "^0.1.6",
    "drupal/admin_toolbar": "^3.1",
    "drupal/auto_entitylabel": "^3.0",
    "drupal/better_exposed_filters": "^6.0.3",
    "drupal/blazy": "^2.5",
    "drupal/block_class": "^2.0.11",
    "drupal/block_field": "1.x.dev",
    "drupal/block_visibility_groups": "^2.0.1",
    "drupal/ckeditor_indentblock": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/ckeditor_media_embed": "^1.0",
    "drupal/classy_paragraphs": "^1.0@beta",
    "drupal/config_filter": "^2.6.0",
    "drupal/config_split": "^2.0.0",
    "drupal/config_update": "^2.0@alpha",
    "drupal/contact_block": "^2.0.2",
    "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": "^10",
    "drupal/core-project-message": "^10",
    "drupal/core-recommended": "^10",
    "drupal/ctools": "^4.0.4",
    "drupal/devel": "^5.1.2",
    "drupal/dropzonejs": "^2.5",
    "drupal/ds": "^3.1",
    "drupal/editor_advanced_link": "^2.0",
    "drupal/editor_file": "^2.0@RC",
    "drupal/entity_browser": "^2.10.0",
    "drupal/entity_embed": "~1.0-beta2",
    "drupal/facets": "^2.0.6",
    "drupal/features": "^3.14",
    "drupal/field_group": "^3.1",
    "drupal/file_browser": "~1.1",
    "drupal/filebrowser": "^3 || ^3.1@RC",
    "drupal/geolocation": "^3.7",
    "drupal/google_tag": "^2.0.4",
    "drupal/iframe": "^2.15",
    "drupal/image_link_attributes": "~1.0",
    "drupal/lang_dropdown": "^2.1",
    "drupal/link_class": "^2",
    "drupal/maxlength": "^2.1",
    "drupal/metatag": "^2.0.0",
    "drupal/paragraphs": "^1.1",
    "drupal/recaptcha": "^3.0",
    "drupal/search_api": "^1.3",
    "drupal/slick": "^2.4",
    "drupal/slick_extras": "~1.0-beta2",
    "drupal/slick_views": "^2.0",
    "drupal/smtp": "~1.0-beta3",
    "drupal/telephone_validation": "^2.3",
    "drupal/token": "^1.0@RC",
    "drupal/token_filter": "^2.1.0",
    "drupal/transliterate_filenames": "^2.0.2",
    "drupal/typed_data_explorer": "^1.0",
    "drupal/video_embed_field": "^2.4",
    "drupal/views_ajax_history": "^1.5",
    "drupal/views_infinite_scroll": "^2.0",
    "drupal/views_slideshow": "^5.0.0",
    "drush/config-extra": "^1.0",
    "giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php": "^8.12",
    "mglaman/composer-drupal-lenient": "^1.0",
    "symfony/filesystem": "^6.4",
    "symfony/finder": "^6.4",
    "webflo/drupal-finder": "^1.0.0",
    "webmozart/path-util": "^2.3",
    "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": "^2"
  },
  "require-dev": {
    "behat/mink": "^1.11",
    "behat/mink-browserkit-driver": "^2.2",
    "drupal/core-dev": "^10",
    "drupal/pathauto": "^1.8",
    "symfony/css-selector": "^6.4"
  },
  "conflict": {
    "drupal/drupal": "*"
  },
  "minimum-stability": "dev",
  "prefer-stable": true,
  "config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "autoloader-suffix": "Drupal8",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "allow-plugins": {
      "composer/installers": true,
      "dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer": true,
      "drupal/console-extend-plugin": true,
      "cweagans/composer-patches": true,
      "davidbarratt/custom-installer": true,
      "drupal/core-composer-scaffold": true,
      "drupal/core-project-message": true,
      "wikimedia/composer-merge-plugin": true,
      "mglaman/composer-drupal-lenient": true,
      "php-http/discovery": true,
      "phpstan/extension-installer": true,
      "drupal-composer/preserve-paths": true
    }
  },
  "autoload": {
    "classmap": [
      "scripts/composer/ScriptHandler.php"
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "drupal-scaffold": "DrupalComposer\\DrupalScaffold\\Plugin::scaffold",
    "pre-install-cmd": ["DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"],
    "pre-update-cmd": ["DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::checkComposerVersion"],
    "post-install-cmd": ["DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles"],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "DrupalProject\\composer\\ScriptHandler::createRequiredFiles",
      "git add ."
    ]
  },
  "extra": {
    "_readme": [
      "By default Drupal loads the autoloader from ./vendor/autoload.php.",
      "To change the autoloader you can edit ./autoload.php.",
      "This file specifies the packages.drupal.org repository.",
      "You can read more about this composer repository at:",
      "https://www.drupal.org/node/2718229"
    ],
    "drupal-scaffold": {
      "excludes": [
        ".editorconfig",
        ".editorconfig",
        ".gitattributes",
        ".gitignore",
        "robots.txt"
      ],
      "omit-defaults": false
    },
    "installer-paths": {
      "core": ["type:drupal-core"],
      "libraries/{$name}": ["type:drupal-library"],
      "modules/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-module"],
      "modules/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-module"],
      "profiles/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-profile"],
      "profiles/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-profile"],
      "themes/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-theme"],
      "themes/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-theme"],
      "drush/contrib/{$name}": ["type:drupal-drush"],
      "drush/custom/{$name}": ["type:drupal-custom-drush"]
    },
    "preserve-paths": [
      "./modules",
      "./profiles",
      "./sites",
      "./themes"
    ],
    "enable-patching": true,
    "patches-ignore": {
    },
    "patches-file": "composer.patches.json"
  }
}
```

I've googled the error message, I've googled `drupal-composer/preserve-paths` package type errors, I've asked the question on Drupal forum, but got no answer or resolution.

Please help me understand the root of the problem and how I can solve it.

Comment: Check that all paths defined on your composer.json file exist.